# проверка подключения к интернету не работает, плагин connectivity

Tags: flutter, dart

При запуске приложения, надпись по центру Hello World!. После нажатия на кнопку Check теоретически должна появиться одно из сообщений о подключении интернета или его отсутствии. Ничего не происходит. Почему? Далее полный код и скриншот. 
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str = 'Hello World!';

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 Future<void> _funCheckInternetConnection() async {

  ConnectivityResult result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

  if(result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
   setState(() {
    _str = 'connected to a mobile network';
   });
  } else if(result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
   setState(() {
    _str = 'connected to a wifi network';
   });
  } else if(result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
   setState(() {
    _str = 'disconnected to a network';
   });
  }

 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () { _funCheckInternetConnection(); },
      child: Container(
       width: 100.0,
       height: 50.0,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black12,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(10.0)
        )
       ),
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child: Text(
        'Check',
        style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 20,
         color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 26.0,
       color: Colors.pink
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По скриншоту угадать невозможно... Приложи дебаг-вывод (в первую очередь, стоит выяснить успешно ли выполняется вызов `checkConnectivity`, и что именно он возвращает по факту).

Comment: А если так `onPressed: () async { await _funCheckInternetConnection(); },`?

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо. Получилось. Оформите это как ответ, что бы его засчитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить нужный результат, нам достаточно добавить `await`, так как метод `_funCheckInternetConnection` является асинхронным:

```
onPressed: () async { await _funCheckInternetConnection(); },
```